# Android What is the equivalent java code for `<item android:left="10dp">`?

Tags: java, android

What is the equivalent java code for `<item android:left="10dp">`?

To be more specific I am trying to get a Bitmap programatically that is equivalent to:

```
<item android:left="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <bitmap 
        android:src="@drawable/screw"
        android:gravity="bottom|left" />
</item>
```

**Edit**

So far I got:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap screw = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);    
BitmapDrawable s = new BitmapDrawable(res, screw);
s.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you are looking for LayoutParams for positioning. Can you tell me what type of view this item is in?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie It is one of the items inside a `<layer-list>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inflate the view from xml pretty easily or if you are loading the drawables programmatically you should use the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html

It has been a while since I worked with java/android but something like this.

```
Drawable[] layers = [drawable1, drawable2, etc]
LayerDrawable mDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
//mDrawable.setLayerInset(int index, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
//you will have to manually calculate density pixels.
mDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 5, 0, 0, 5)
```

Comment: But, you are setting the inset on the LayerDrawable, not on a specific Item. ::: What if I have two items each with different insets? ::: The BitmapDrawable class does not have a `setLayerInset()` method or similar, nor the Bitmap class.

Comment: Have another look. The first argument to [`setLayerInset`](http://goo.gl/zqzMm) is the item index.

Comment: @ilomambo As Jeremy said the you use the index of the drawable in the array to assign the inset. So mDrawable.setLayerInset(0, 5, 0, 0, 5) for the first, mDrawable.setLayerInset(1, 10, 0, 0, 10) for the second, etc.